# Alternative to np.insert in tensorflow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

There is a function in numpy that inserts given values to the array:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html

Is there something similar in tensorflow?

Alternatively, is there a function in tensorflow that can do tensor upsampling using zeros in between values of a tensor?

Answer (score 0):

`tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` can do this upsampling (with careful design of `output_shape` and `strides`). A sample code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.ones((1, 20, 20, 1)))
input = tf.cast(input, tf.float32)
b = np.zeros((3, 3, 1, 1))
b[1, 1, 0, 0] = 1
weight = tf.convert_to_tensor(b)
weight = tf.cast(weight, tf.float32)
output = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(input, weight, output_shape=(1, 40, 40, 1), strides=[1, 2, 2, 1])

sess = tf.Session()

print sess.run(output[0, :, :, 0])
```

I believe checking its api will help you more.